# How to refer dynamic range from another sheet to active sheet cell through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am not getting dynamic range work sheet name in formula. Can anyone assist on this? I get the active sheet range in the formula as `=COUNTIF(I3:I31,A3)`

```
Sub Test_DaySumm()

Dim Rg As Range
wksMain.Select
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wksMain

If ws1.FilterMode = True Then ws1.ShowAllData
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = ws1.Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(LastRow, 9))

wksDaySummary.Select
xRow = 3
Do Until wksDaySummary.Cells(xRow, 1) = ""
    Set Rg = wksDaySummary.Cells(xRow, 2)
    Rg.Formula = "=COUNTIF( " & MyRange.Address(0, 0) & "," & Rg.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
    Rg.Value = Rg.Value
    xRow = xRow + 1
DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That's not clear, what do you want the formula to read? Your MyRange line should be fully qualified with sheet references.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Out put is 0 and formula output is (=COUNTIF(I3:I31,A3)), myrange is taking current active sheet range(wksDaySummary) value in stead of ws1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [Range.Address Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) documentary

> ```
> .Address(RowAbsolute, ColumnAbsolute, ReferenceStyle, External, RelativeTo)
> ```

and use the `External:=True` parameter get get the worksheet name in the address too:

```
MyRange.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, External:=True)
```

So instead of eg `I3:I31` the result would be like `'Main Sheet'!I3:I31`